# Beamer presentation with Pandoc and Markdown - Using xelatex as the pdf engine doesn't show most Persian fonts properly

Tags: beamer, xetex, pandoc, markdown, persian

I'm trying to create a [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer) presentation using [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc) and [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown), and since I'm writing it in Persian, I need to use `--pdf-engine=xelatex`.

I have a `pres.md` file with this content:

```
---
dir: rtl
title: "روش پژوهش و ارائه"
author: "امیر شبانی"
date: "یک‌شنبه - ۸ دی ۱۳۹۸"
---
```

Now if I use `BNazanin` as the font and compile the file using this command,

```
pandoc pres.md -t beamer -o pres.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="BNazanin"
```

everything works fine and the output is as expected:

[image: BNazanin font works fine]

But if I change it to another font, such as [`sahel`](https://github.com/rastikerdar/sahel-font), it will appear corrupted:

[image: Sahel font doesn't show properly]

As you can see, the font has been detected, and I can verify that it is installed on my system:

[image: Sahel font is installed on my system.]

But it doesn't show properly, and it seems that it has "[zero-width non-joiner (نیم‌فاصله)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner)" between every letter. So for example, it's showing ا‌م‌ی‌ر instead of امیر.

Other fonts I've tried: Shabnam, Vazir, Samim. And they all have the same problem. Is there a way I can fix this, so that I can use a font like Sahel?

Comment: You need to find a way to specify that the font script is to be Arabic, otherwise the font is just loaded with its default English script. (I don't know how to do this with Pandoc.)

Comment: @DavidPurton could you describe how to do this in LaTeX? Plain TeX snippets can be added in pandoc via the `header-includes` metadata field (documented at in the last paragraph [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

compile the file using this command:

```
pandoc pres.md -t beamer -o pres.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Yas" -V lang:ar
```

Output:

[image]

file test.md

```
---
title: "روش پژوهش و ارائه"
author: "امیر شبانی"
date: "دو‌شنبه - ۹ دی ۱۳۹۸"
---
```

compile with:

```
pandoc test.md -t beamer -o test.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Yas" -V lang:ar -V dir:rtl
```

[image]

Or file exam.md

```
---
lang: ar
dir: rtl
title: "روش پژوهش و ارائه"
author: "امیر شبانی"
date: "یک‌شنبه - ۸ دی ۱۳۹۸"
---
```

compile:

```
pandoc exam.md -t beamer -o exam.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Yas"
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!